# Create new product magento failing REST API

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have been trying to create a simple product via REST API
as mentioned [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html).

But i was unable to add a product.
I was able to fetch products from magento REST api.. 
but not creating it for magento, tried google alot but couldn't found any helpful post.
The same problem is reported even [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/295499/).

Kindly help.

Comment: it seems that you can create product as Admin via OAuth authentication, take a look there http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-CreateasimpleproductasanAdminuserwithOAuthauthentication

Comment: @AnasBouhtouch: Thanks for responding..

The link i'have mentioned in my question is same as you have given me.
It would be great if you could suggest me with a working example for the same.

Thanks